# Css arrow to content tab box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I have a easy responsive content tab. I want to add css arrow to the content box which should point towards the respective menu item.

How do I get it dynamically for each tab content boxes.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#verticalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
        type: 'vertical',
        width: 'auto',
        fit: true
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/odAkAXI/1/)**

Comment: Do you mean you want an arrow on the currently selected box? Since the selection applies a class to an element, you can add the styles for an arrow using said class.

Comment: I need arrow to right panel which holds content of the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.resp-vtabs .resp-tabs-list li` then add the following CSS:

```
.resp-vtabs .resp-tabs-list li.resp-tab-active:after {
   content: ""; 
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   right: -5%;
   top: 0;
   border: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right-color: red;
}
```

You can change the `border-right-color` to change the color of the arrow.

http://jsbin.com/odAkAXI/4/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!! But it is not working in IE 8. Any solution??

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `rgba(0,0,0,0)` use `transparent` instead. Going to update the answer.